# Android Studio 4.2.2 Native dependencies in AARs buildFeatures.prefab=true - Missing argument "PACKAGE_PATH"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

Android Studio 4.2.2

Adding Build Feature Prefab for Prefab AAR Shared Library Android.mk/CMake Build:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/native-dependencies?buildsystem=cmake&agpversion=4.1

Following Documentation perfectly for Android Studio 4.1+ and using Build Features

```
android {
        buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
        ndkVersion '22.1.7171670'
    
        buildFeatures {
            prefab true
        }
}
```

### Problem:

```
Error while executing java process with main class com.google.prefab.cli.AppKt with arguments {--build-system ndk-build --platform android --abi armeabi-v7a --os-version 21 --stl c++_static --ndk-version 22 --output /Users/~var/Documents/project/.cxx/ndkBuild/debug/prefab/armeabi-v7a/prefab}

Usage: prefab [OPTIONS] [PACKAGE_PATH]...

Error: Missing argument "PACKAGE_PATH".
```

**Error: Missing argument "PACKAGE_PATH".**

Comment: What does the rest of your build.gradle look like? There's not enough here to diagnose.

Comment: I think the problem was I had no linked "Prefab" at all in the Android.mk linked from the build.gradle after calling buildFeatures { prefab true } so this error for the project  was generated.

Adding a secondary library project as a prefab via my proposed solution fixed the error and linked and compiled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting this:

```
buildFeatures {
        prefab true
    }
```

You must then Link to an existing prefab published module after setting that command else this error occurs

If you are not using prefabs at all Remove this line and it will compile

OR either can Link to an Active Prefab via the Android.mk or CMakeLists

Android.mk

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
$(call import-add-path, $(LOCAL_PATH)/modulePath)
$(call import-add-path, /../../anotherModulePath)
# If you don't need your project to build with NDKs older than r21, you can omit
# this block.
ifneq ($(call ndk-major-at-least,21),true)
    $(call import-add-path,$(NDK_GRADLE_INJECTED_IMPORT_PATH))
Endif
# the linked prefab published module project location 
$(call import-module, openFrameworksAndroid)
```

If you need to build your module library with type of Prefab set the gradle setting buildFeatures.prefabPublishing true and configure these extra commands

```
// Enable generation of Prefab packages and include them in the library's AAR.
buildFeatures {
    prefabPublishing true
}

// Include the "mylibrary" module from the native build system in the AAR,
// and export the headers in src/main/cpp/include to its consumers
prefab {
    openFrameworksAndroid {
        //headers "src/main/cpp/include"
    }
}

// Avoid packing the unnecessary libraries into final AAR. For details
// refer to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168777344#comment5
// Note that if your AAR also contains Java/Kotlin APIs, you should not
// exclude libraries that are used by those APIs.
packagingOptions {
    exclude("**/libopenFrameworksAndroid.so")
    exclude("**/classes.jar")
}
```

Example:

https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/prefab

More Documentation:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/native-dependencies?buildsystem=ndk-build&agpversion=4.1

Comment: The docs for consuming prefab packages are correct. You instructions are for publishing them, which is not what the OP was doing based on their build.gradle.

Comment: @DanAlbert this error occurs if you add using prefab when no prefab is in fact used. That's what the answer is about. Either Do not use this command or make sure your prefab is setup correctly / linked correctly in appropriate build system

Comment: I got error Could not find method prefabPublishing() for arguments [true]